# Excel calculated values sum Discrepancy

Tags: excel

I have found that using the SUM() function to add a column of calculated values provides a different result than using the SUM() function against raw values. The following screen shots show a 1cent discrepancy between the sum of two columns that appear identical, except one is a calculated column and the other is raw data entry:
[Note sum on column c is 1 cent different than column d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6cU6.png)

[See the sum formula in row 22 is a simple sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYUSg.png)

Comment: Anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the calculated values are not rounded to the 2nd decimal, they are just shown that way.  But some of numbers may show 9.98 but really be 9.978.

If you want to see what I mean increase the decimal shown in those cells to four or more places.

To avoid this you can wrap the formulas in the range with `=ROUND(...,2)`, where he `...` is your formula. This will round the results to two places and then the two sums will match.